# How can I combine two COUNT functions to get a query that shows where two IDs appear more than 5 times in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query that will pull information that shows where more than 5 items were borrowed by more than 5 people.

```
    SELECT Person_Name, Item_Name
    FROM Item
    JOIN Person ON Item.Person_ID = Person.Person_ID
    WHERE Item_ID IN 
        (SELECT Item_ID, Person_ID
        FROM Item 
            GROUP BY Item_ID, Person_ID
            HAVING COUNT (Item_ID) > 5 AND COUNT (Person_ID) >5)
```

The error I keep getting is "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: just dont select `person_id`, the group by shouldn't care. if you do `where in (select ` you can only select 1 column

Comment: To elaborate on @chiliNUT comment, remove `Person_ID` from your sub-query and you'll be fine. To understand this, in a separate window execute your sub-query with, and without `Person_ID` in the select list and you'll see the only difference is the column isn't returned, but the grouping still exists. Also, you may want `count (distinct Item_ID)`, it's hard to be sure from the question.

Comment: Could you provide sample data and desired results?  Do you mean the *same* 5 items by the *same* 5 people?

Comment: I'm not sure how to read "where more than 5 items were borrowed by more than 5 people"... Right now the query (when working without the `PersonID` in the inner `SELECT`) selects all items who have been borrowed by the __same__ person more than five times, plus any person who ever borrowed such an item, regardless of how often. If I'm not terribly mistaking something. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `Person_ID` in the subquery

```
SELECT Person_Name, Item_Name
    FROM Item
    JOIN Person ON Item.Person_ID = Person.Person_ID
    WHERE Item_ID IN 
        (SELECT Item_ID
        FROM Item 
            GROUP BY Item_ID, Person_ID
            HAVING COUNT (Item_ID) > 5 AND COUNT (Person_ID) >5)
```

Comment: It is now producing the Table, but it does not show any of the results. Not sure why that is happening as I did confirm that the table had more than 5 items and people tied to it.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret the question as five items purchased by five or more people, it would start by getting each person that have 5 or more items and all possible items:

```
select person_id, i1.item_id as item1, i2.item_id as item2, i3.item_id as item3, i4.item_id as item4, i5.item_id as item5
from items i1 join
     items i2
     on i1.person_id = i2.person_id and i1.item_id < i2.item_id join
     items i3
     on i1.person_id = i3.person_id and i2.item_id < i3.item_id join
     items i4
     on i1.person_id = i4.person_id and i3.item_id < i4.item_id join
     items i5
     on i1.person_id = i5.person_id and i4.item_id < i5.item_id;
```

Then it would use this to get the the items that have five or more people:

```
select item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, count(*) as num_people
from (select person_id, i1.item_id as item1, i2.item_id as item2, i3.item_id as item3, i4.item_id as item4, i5.item_id as item5
      from items i1 join
           items i2
           on i1.person_id = i2.person_id and i1.item_id < i2.item_id join
           items i3
           on i1.person_id = i3.person_id and i2.item_id < i3.item_id join
           items i4
           on i1.person_id = i4.person_id and i3.item_id < i4.item_id join
           items i5
           on i1.person_id = i5.person_id and i4.item_id < i5.item_id
      ) pi
group by item1, item2, item3, item4, item5
having count(*) >= 5;
```