# I need my query to return where it will return where an item was purchased by more than 3 customers. However, my query keeps returning Null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have confirmed that there is instances where an item was purchased more than 3 times by 3 SEPERATE customers. However, my code keeps returning Null. I have tried several different variations of the code below, but I get either Null or an error message stating "Ambiguous column name 'Customer_ID'."

I have also tried aliasing it, but with no luck. Where am I going wrong?

```
   SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Country, Address, State, Zip, Product_Name

   FROM Orders

   JOIN Customer ON Orders.Customer_ID = Customer.Customer_ID
   JOIN Amazon_Inventory ON Orders.Inventory_ID = Amazon_Inventory.Inventory_ID
   JOIN Shipment ON Amazon_Inventory.Shipment_ID = Shipment.Shipment_ID
   JOIN Product ON Shipment.Product_ID = Product.Product_ID
   JOIN Product_Listing ON Product.Listing_ID = Product_Listing.Listing_ID

   WHERE ORDER_ID IN 
       (SELECT Customer_ID, Inventory_ID 
       FROM Orders 
           GROUP BY Customer_ID, Inventory_ID 
           HAVING COUNT (Order_ID) >3 AND COUNT (INVENTORY_ID) >3);
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Expected Results would be listing 3 customers who all purchased a product X and the customers names/addresses, while filtering out an instance where 1 customer bought 3 of product X.

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same problem from your other question [How can I combine two COUNT functions to get a query that shows where two IDs appear more than 5 times in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010422/how-can-i-combine-two-count-functions-to-get-a-query-that-shows-where-two-ids-ap#comment87039121_50010422)?

Comment: What is an inventory id and is there more than one per order?

Answer (score 0):

The error is on `IN` subquery,you can't use `IN` to compare multiple fields.

If I understand correct you might expect this.

You could provide some sample data and expect result.I will edit my answer.

```
SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Country, Address, State, Zip, Product_Name
FROM Orders
JOIN Customer ON Orders.Customer_ID = Customer.Customer_ID
JOIN Amazon_Inventory ON Orders.Inventory_ID = Amazon_Inventory.Inventory_ID
JOIN Shipment ON Amazon_Inventory.Shipment_ID = Shipment.Shipment_ID
JOIN Product ON Shipment.Product_ID = Product.Product_ID
JOIN Product_Listing ON Product.Listing_ID = Product_Listing.Listing_ID
WHERE Customer.Customer_ID IN 
   (SELECT Customer_ID
   FROM Orders 
       GROUP BY Customer_ID
       HAVING COUNT (1) >3 );
```

Comment: Hi D-Shih, I tried the answer you gave and got this error: 

"Column 'Orders.Order_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I'll toy around with it to see if I can get anything to work from it. What type of sample data? The database is rather large and relies on 6 tables to pull the information.

Comment: Could you show some data from `Orders` table? that really help

Comment: CREATE TABLE Orders(Order_ID VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY          KEY, Customer_ID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
         Payment_ID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, INVENTORY_ID          VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, Shipment_Speed VARCHAR(25) NOT          NULL);
         INSERT INTO Orders(Order_ID, Customer_ID, Payment_ID,          Inventory_ID, Shipment_Speed)
         VALUES
         (811, 1, 82, 9001, 'Overnight'),
         (812, 1, 81, 9002, 'Two Day'),
         (813, 5, 86, 9001, 'Two Day'),
         (814, 3, 84, 9001, 'Standard'),
         (815, 2, 83, 9004, 'Standard');

Comment: You can try my edit answer, and you migth put your table info in your question Instead of comment:)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. I would suggest you to use alias to your tables (that would solve the ambiguous errors), and also, you are using an `IN` referring to a `SELECT` with more than 1 column being selected (A tip: I would use an `EXISTS` instead of a `IN` whenever possible - but that's not the case - or at least it doesn't seems like the case with the info provided).

So, using aliases I would end up with something like this:

`SELECT 
     *
     /* Place appropriate alias in each field selected => First_Name, Last_Name, Country, Address, State, Zip, Product_Name */
  FROM Orders AS OR
    JOIN Customer         AS CU ON Orders.Customer_ID = Customer.Customer_ID
    JOIN Amazon_Inventory AS AI ON Orders.Inventory_ID = Amazon_Inventory.Inventory_ID
    JOIN Shipment         AS SH ON Amazon_Inventory.Shipment_ID = Shipment.Shipment_ID
    JOIN Product          AS PR ON Shipment.Product_ID = Product.Product_ID
    JOIN Product_Listing  AS PL ON Product.Listing_ID = Product_Listing.Listing_ID
  WHERE 
    EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM Orders OREX 
        WHERE OREX.Inventory_ID = OR.Inventory_ID 
        GROUP BY OREX.Customer_ID, OREX.Inventory_ID 
        HAVING COUNT(1)>3);`

Comment: If I was to use the exist function, how would that appear? I tried it earlier, but I am still a little shaky on using that query.

Comment: Your subquery is invalid because the "OREDER_ID" doesn't appear in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You would have to include the tables definitions for me to help you on that. With provided info, It's not a preferable option, since you're not grouping the subquery by Order_ID.

Comment: Woops. Sorry, @eclecticist is right. Let me correct that... Just a sec.

Comment: Found what seems to be another "logic" error on that query... Give me a moment and I'll bring it up.

Comment: @Sleepy_Hollows_4, in that subquery, what exactly are you trying to select? All Orders that have a same Inventory_ID from other 2 Orders from different Customers. Is that it?

Comment: Aliasing tables doesn't fix an ambiguous column error. Qualifying your column names, everywhere, with either the full [database].[schema].[table] qualifier or the alias that you assign to the full qualifier will fix the ambiguous column error.

Comment: @Eric Brandt, agreed. It's just a pragmatic way to tell the OP that he is not qualifying the columns correctly and that, maybe, using short aliases could help him achieve that.

Comment: @MarceloMyara, I was fairly confident you knew what you meant. I was just in a particularly nit-picky mindset when I read your answer, so I gave in to the urge to clarify. Most days I would have read right past it. No criticism of you or your answer intended. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking something like this:

```
SELECT 
    c.Customer_ID, i.Inventory_ID,
    c.First_Name, c.Last_Name, c.Country, c.Address, c.State, c.Zip,
    p.Product_Name
FROM Orders o
    JOIN Customer c         ON o.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID
    JOIN Amazon_Inventory i ON o.Inventory_ID = i.Inventory_ID
    JOIN Shipment s         ON i.Shipment_ID = s.Shipment_ID
    JOIN Product p          ON s.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
    JOIN Product_Listing l  ON p.Listing_ID = l.Listing_ID
)
WHERE Inventory_ID IN (
    SELECT Inventory_ID
    FROM Orders JOIN Customer ON Orders.Customer_ID = Customer.Customer_ID
    GROUP BY Inventory_ID 
    HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT Customer_ID) > 3
);
```